# Casperjs not extracting value of the class

Tags: javascript, jquery, casperjs

I am using CasperJS to log into hasjob.co and scrape some information from the homepage.

I did most of the work fine, like getting things clicked and logining in with jquery, but I am stuck at actually extracting the value of the tag that I want.

I use the below code to do the extract, it seem to extract something, but most of it empty but with a comma

```
casper.waitForSelector(x('//*[@id="hg-networkbar-hasjob"]/a'), function(){
    casper.click(x('//*[@id="hg-networkbar-hasjob"]/a'));
});
```

The result of our ecoho look like this

```
- ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Full code below:

```
var links = [];



function getLinks() {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('.annotation bottom-right');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(e) {
        return e.getAttribute('value');
    });
}

var casper = require('casper').create({

    clientScripts: ['/Users/doddarliu/Desktop/jquery.min.js']
});

var x = require('casper').selectXPath;

casper.options.viewportSize = {width: 1600, height: 950};

phantom.cookiesEnabled = true;

var fs = require('fs');
var cookies= JSON.stringify(phantom.cookies);

fs.write('cookies.txt', cookies, 644);

casper.userAgent('Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)');

casper.start('https://auth.hasgeek.com/login');

// casper.on("resource.error", function(msg, trace) {
//     this.echo("Error: " + msg, "ERROR");
// });


// casper.then( function() {

//  this.sendkeys('')

// });


casper.then( function() {
    casper.capture('test.png');
});


casper.waitForSelector(x('//*[@id="main-content"]/div[2]/div[2]/p/a[2]'), function(){
    casper.click(x('//*[@id="main-content"]/div[2]/div[2]/p/a[2]'));
});

casper.waitForSelector(x('//*[@id="Passwd"]'), function(){
    this.thenEvaluate(function() {
        $('#Email').val('username');
        $('#Passwd').val('pass');
    });

});

// casper.wait(5000);
casper.then( function() {
    casper.click(x('//*[@id="signIn"]'));
});


casper.waitForSelector(x('//*[@id="hg-networkbar-hasjob"]/a'), function(){
    casper.click(x('//*[@id="hg-networkbar-hasjob"]/a'));
});

casper.wait(5000);

casper.then( function() {
    casper.capture('test2.png');
});

casper.then(function() {
    // aggregate results for the 'casperjs' search

    links = casper.getElementsAttribute('.annotation.bottom-right', 'value');
});

casper.run(function() {
    // echo results in some pretty fashion
    this.echo(' - ' + links.toString()).exit();
});
```

Sample markup:

```
<span class="annotation bottom-right">Fashionhaat</span>
```

and I want to extract "Fashionhaat"

Comment: <span class="annotation bottom-right">Fashionhaat</span> and I want to extract "Fashionhaat"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to extract the `value` attribute. You want to get the text of the element. `casper.getElementsInfo()` delivers the `text` property. You can filter it to your needs:

```
links = casper.getElementsInfo('.annotation.bottom-right').map(function(e){
    return e.text;
});
```